# How to get the selected item of ComboBox of actionscript 3 by javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

Can someone provide an example how to do this?

**UPDATE**

I know how to get the selected item in actionscript,but my question is how to get it in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Get the selected item in AS3 and pass it out to javascript using External Interface:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html